# Что такое Канал сервера LyX?

Tags: lyx

В LyX, в **Инструменты>Настройки>Пути**, есть текстовое поле *Канал сервера LyX*. Что туда вписывают и для чего оно нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, эта функция нужна для организации взаимодействия LyX с другими программами. В частности, оказывается, в открытое окно программы LyX можно вводить команды через командную строку! Прежде всего, чтобы это все сработало, в названное в формулировке вопроса текстовое поле *Канал сервера LyX* вписываем следующее:

```
\\.\pipe\lyxpipe
```

, причем к `lyxpipe`, к окончанию, **не приписываем** ни .in, ни .out. Естественно, жмем `Сохранить`. Далее, окно программы LyX, в которое возникла потребность вводить команды из окна командной строки, должно быть запущено раньше этой командной строки, из которой будут вводиться команды в это окно программы LyX, иначе ничего не получится. Вот примеры, как нужно писать команды в командной строке, чтобы это получилось:

```
echo LYXCMD:sohranenie:buffer-write> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
echo LYXCMD:formula:math-mode:\alpha> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
echo LYXCMD:vstgrafiki:inset-apply:graphics filename zdes kujut hip-hop.png> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
```

На мой взгляд, интерес заслуживает последняя команда. Эта команда вставляет фотку *zdes kujut hip-hop.png* )), находящуюся в папке, указанной в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути** в текстовом поле *Каталог пользователя* в открытое (до открытия командной строки) окно программы LyX.