# Как в LyX настраивать прямой и обратный поиск?

Tags: lyx

Прежде всего, всех с Рождеством Христовым! Собственно, у меня это несеолько лет не получалось. Сейчас я это умею делать. Вот, хочу поделиться. Настройка довольно-таки тонкая, так что лучше то, что будет в ответе к этому, не редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

Как это настраивается, рассказано [вот здесь](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473572/lyx-2-3-how-can-i-successfully-set-up-the-forward-and-inverse-search). Я просто расскажу, как это делал я на русском языке. Итак. Мы используем непортабельную версию SumatraPDF. Вот мы ее скачали, установили. Далее в "Пуск>Программы по умолчанию>Сопоставление типов файлов или протоколов отдельным программам" делаем так, чтобы файлы `.pdf` открывались с помощью SumatraPDF. Затем идем в папку `C:\Users\ИВАН\AppData\Roaming\SumatraPDF`. Оттуда, следуя совету по приведенной ссылке, скопируем в какое-нибудь место файл *SumatraPDF-settings.txt. Далее нужно было добавить каким-либо способом путь к папке, содержащей открывающий программу SumatraPDF файл (у меня это папка `C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF`) в РАТН. Я почему-то добавил это в *Переменные среды пользователя для ИВАН*. Далее, путь к папке, содержащей файл, запускающий программу LyX (у меня это `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\bin`), тоже должен содержаться в РАТН. Далее, пойдем в папку  `C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF`, откроем файл *SumatraPDF.exe*. В появившемся окне программы SumatraPDF щелкаем левой кнопкой мышки 3 горизонтальные полоски в левом верхнем углу (а, может, угле)) ), далее, **Настройки>Расширенные настройки**. При этом в блокноте откроется тот самый файл SumatraPDF-settings.txt, копию которого мы до этого поместили в какое-нибудь укромное место, так что теперь с этим файлом мы можем делать все, что нам заблагорассудится. А делать мы станем с ним следующее. Вот список некоторых переменных вместе со своими значениями:

```
ReuseInstance = true
ReloadModifiedDocuments = true
InverseSearchCmdLine = lyxeditor.cmd "%f" %l
EnableTeXEnhancements = true
UseTabs = true
```

Так вот. В файле SumatraPDF-settings.txt проверяем наличие этих переменных (слов, стоящих слева от знака равенства), если они там есть, мы проверяем совпадения значения (слов, стоящих справа от знака равенства) найденных в этом файле переменных из приведенного списка со значениями таких же переменных из этого списка. Если бы в приведенном списке значение какой-либо переменной отличалось от значения соответствующей переменной, в файле, нужно было бы переделать значение этой переменной на такое же, как из приведенного выше списка. Если бы какой-либо переменной из списка вместе со своим значением не было в файле, нам бы просто нужно было скопировать переменную вместе с ее значением в файл. Ну, лично я ничего не менял в этом файле: все перечисленные в списке переменные уже существовали в файле и всем этим переменным в файле присвоились соответствующие значения, приведенные в списке, непосредственно при установке SumatraPDF. Закрываем, сохраняем изменения.  Все, SumatraPDF после этого станет настроена. Переходим к настройке LyX. Итак, открываем программу LyX, если до сих пор она не была открыта или по каким-то причинам была закрыта. Идем в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути**. В текстовое поле *Канал сервера LyX* вписываем

```
\\.\pipe\lyxpipe
```

Далее идем в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Обработка файлов>Конверторы**. Там в области под словосочетанием *Определения конверторов* выбираем левой кнопкой мышки *LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)*. Далее удаляем из текстового поля *Конвертер* его содержимое и вставляем (ну, или вписываем руками) следующее:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 $$i
```

А из текстового поля *Дополнительно* удаляем его содержимое. Нажимаем кнопку `Изменить`. Затем `Сохранить`. Повторно заходим в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Обработка файлов>Конверторы**. Проверяем, сохранились ли настройки. У меня, когда я туда вот сейчас, при работающих в обе стороны поисках, вхожу, после нажатия левой кнопкой мышки *LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)*, то место настроек выглядит так:

[image]

Далее идем в **Инструменты>Настройки..>Вывод>Общие**. Там в текстовое поле *Команда PDF* вводим следующую команду:

```
SumatraPDF -forward-search "$$t" $$n "$$o"
```

, нажимаем `Применить`. Таким образом, это место станет выглядеть так:

[image]

Пойдем в **Инструменты>Настройки..>Обработка файлов>Форматы файлов**. Там в выпадающем списке ***Формат*** установим, выбирая левой кнопкой мышки значение *PDF (pdflatex)*, в выпадающем списке ***Просмотрщик*** значение *Задано пользователем*, а в текстовое поле справа от этого списка вписываем

```
SumatraPDF
```

В настоящий момент там так:

[image]

И, наконец, в папке `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\bin` создаем файл с именем *lyxeditor* и расширением *.cmd* (по сути, получается, это тот же батник) следующего содержания:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set file=%1
set row=%2
REM remove quotes from variables
set file=!file:"=!
set row=!row:"=!
%comspec% /q /c (@echo 
LYXCMD:revdvi:server-goto-file-row:%file% 
%row%)> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in&&type 
\\.\pipe\lyxpipe.out
endlocal
```

код этого батника я взял [отсюда](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX), когда перешел по ссылке на странице на английском языке, содержание которой я здесь пересказываю (ссылка на эту страницу дана мной здесь, только выше). Честно говоря, про создание батника на странице на английском языке рассказано намного раньше, чем это сделано у меня, но какая разница? Кстати, код этого батника натолкнул меня на мысль, как вводить команды в командную строку, чтобы они с этой строки вводились в открытое окно программы LyX, что послужило почвой для написания [вот этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066881/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-lyx/1066882#1066882). А до этого я пробовал вставлять команды из командной строки в окно программы LyX, беря эти команды из мануала, например, пытался выполнить из командной строки такую команду:

```
echo "LYXCMD:test:get-xy:" >~/.lyxpipe.in
```

, но у меня ничего не получалось. Ну, и вот, возвращаясь к поиску, связанному с LyX. Как этим пользоваться? А очень просто. Вот если мы сделали предпросмотр открытого файла `.lyx`, то при нажатии **Навигация>Forward search** на короткое время в соответствующем окне SumatraPDF выделяется фиолетовым (по крайней мере, у меня) цветом несколько строк, содержащих то же слово, около соответствующему которому в окне LyX в настоящий момент мигает курсор. При двойном щелчке в окне SumatraPDF  фокус переносится в окно LyX и там начинает мигать курсор, при этом при щелчке в разных местах окна SumatraPDF курсор начинает мигать в разных местах окна LyX. Ничего более конкретного о связи положения курсора в LyX со строками, выделяемыми в SumatraPDF, ровно как и о связи положения двойного щелчка в SumatraPDF с местом в окне LyX, в котором начинает мигать курсор, сказать не могу.