# Автоматизация в программе LyX с помощью файлов .bat

Tags: lyx

Когда я научился настраивать [прямой и обратный поиск в программе LyX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066935/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA), мне стало интересно, а нельзя ли в этой программе использовать файлы .bat для автоматизации каких-либо действий. Кто-нибудь может мне что-нибудь подсказать по этому поводу?

Answer (score 1):

Хочу рассказать, что мне удалось надыбать по этому поводу. Итак. Несмотря на кажущееся на первый взгляд отсутствие возможности добавления в LyX новых форматов экспорта (насколько я понимаю, например, в TeXworks аналогом такой возможности добавления является возможность создания нового инструмента верстки), в этой программе такая возможность присутствует. Для начала попробуем создать следующий, кажущийся на первый взгляд баловством, формат экспорта. В программе LyX определены следующие переменные PATH:

```
$$s The LyX system directory (e. g. /usr/share/lyx).
$$i The input file
$$o The output file
$$b The base name (without filename extension) in the LyX temporary directory
$$p The full directory path of the LyX temporary directory
$$r The full pathname to the original LyX file being processed
$$f The filename (without any directory path) of the LyX file.
$$l The `LaTeX name'
```

это я привожу отрывок из одной части мануала программы LyX. Мы не будем здесь заниматься переводом объяснений значений, смыслов этих переменных, а вместо этого попробуем создать новый формат экспорта (с появлением новой кнопки в **Файл>Экспортировать в**, в том числе при щелчке по которой мы сможем произвести экспорт в этот формата того файла `.lyx`, из окна которого этот щелчок был произведен), при экспорте в который во временном каталоге (в котором, например, при экспорте в PDF{pdflatex} образуются файлы, помимо создаваемого `.pdf`) будет создаваться файл *puti.txt*, в который будут выведены (все) значения этих переменных. Для этого в папке, которая добавлена в РАТН, создаем файл *puti.bat* следующего содержания:

```
chcp 1251
cd /d %0\..
echo %1 >puti.txt
echo %2 >>puti.txt
echo %3 >>puti.txt
echo %4 >>puti.txt
echo %5 >>puti.txt
echo %6 >>puti.txt
echo %7 >>puti.txt
echo %8 >>puti.txt
echo %1/%~2 >>puti.txt
```

Далее, в файл `C:\Users\ИВАН\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.0\lyxrc.defaults` мы, там, где строки

```
....................................
\Format pdf4 pdf "PDF (XeTeX)" X "pdfview" "" "document,vector,menu=export"
\Format pdf5 pdf "PDF (LuaTeX)" u "pdfview" "" "document,vector,menu=export"
```

добавим такую строку:

```
\Format pdf6 txt "puti" F "pdfview" "" "document,vector,menu=export"
```

Здесь слово *puti* задает не файл с кодом, являющийся движком создаваемого формата экспорта, а то, под каким именем будет отображаться кнопка вызова этого формата экспорта в **Файл>Экспортировать в**, а там, где

```
....................................
\converter pdflatex pdf2 "pdflatex $$i" "latex=pdflatex"
\converter xetex pdf4 "xelatex $$i" "latex=xelatex"
\converter luatex pdf5 "lualatex" "latex=lualatex"
```

мы после строки, определяющей формат pdf5, добавляем такую строку:

```
\converter pdflatex pdf6 "puti.bat $$b $$f $$i $$l $$o $$p $$r $$s" ""
```

А вот здесь слово *puti* задает уже файл с кодом, являющийся движком создаваемого формата экспорта. И в этом месте файла *lyxrc.defaults* уже **нужно обязательно указывать расширение этого файла с кодом (в данном случае `.bat`), иначе ничего работать не будет!**. А дальше, как несложно догадаться, указываются параметры, с одной стороны, с которыми будет запускаться этот файл с кодом при начале экспорта в создаваемый формат, а, с другой стороны, называются эти параметре в форме, которую программа LyX знает, и поэтому при вызове этого файла с кодом из открытого в LyX файла, LyX, перед тем, как открыть файл с кодом соответствующей программой с параметрами, некоторые из которых формируются из частей полного пути к экспортируемому файлу, а другие - из полных путей к каким-то значимым папкам системы, выполняет замену этих параметров, названных в такой форме их, так сказать, почти настоящими значениями, уже почти пригодными для применения в командной строке. Почему "почти" станет ясно потом. Все, больше ничего в файле *lyxrc.defaults* делать не нужно: ни добавлять, там, новый какой-нибудь *\editor_alternatives* или *\viewer_alternatives*, или еще что-то в этом духе... Далее, после сохранения измененного таким образом файла *lyxrc.defaults* и перезапуска программы LyX в **Файл>Экспортировать в** появляется новая кнопка:

[image]

Перед тем, как ее нажать, нажмем **Вид>View Messages** (когда я использовал LyX, установленную из исполняемого файла, скачанного из другого источника, та кнопка называлась *Просмотреть сообщения*, потому что в той копии программы использовался другой файл локализации `.mo`), при этом обычно в нижней части окна программы LyX появляется область под названием *Сообщения прогресса/отладки*. Вот теперь можно нажимать созданную нами кнопку. При этом в области *Сообщения прогресса/отладки* начинают мелькать, прокручиваясь вниз, инфа о течении процесса экспорта. После окончания такого мелькания ищем путь к временной папке, в которой помещаются попутно возникающие файлы, помимо файла того типа, который требуется получить в одной папке с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx`. Все такие пути более-менее сходны друг с другом, так что тут ошибки быть не может. К примеру, вот один из таких путей:

```
D:\1-kat-LyX\lyx_tmpdir.gq2748\lyx_tmpbuf2
```

Переходим в эту папку. Там будет, среди прочих, находиться файл *puti.txt*, который мы и задали в качестве выходного для данного формата экспорта. Открыв его, увидим примерно следующее:

```
D:/1-kat-LyX/lyx_tmpdir.gq2748/lyx_tmpbuf2/newfile2
newfile2.lyx
newfile2.tex
$$l
newfile2.txt
D:/1-kat-LyX/lyx_tmpdir.gq2748/lyx_tmpbuf2/
C:/DocLyX/
$$s
D:/1-kat-LyX/lyx_tmpdir.gq2748/lyx_tmpbuf2/newfile2/newfile2.lyx
```

Файл такого содержания образовался при экспорте в созданный мной формат экспорта файла *C:\DocLyX\newfile2.lyx*. Как видно, даже не все параметры раскрылись в свои значения, что, однако, не мешает созданию еще некоторых форматов экспорта, задуманных мной. Однако тут обнаруживается такая проблема, состоящая в "почти" совместимости с командной строкой, о которой я упоминал выше. Именно: разделителем в полученных таким образом путях в файле выхода .txt является знак `/` вместо традиционного, по крайней мере, для Windows, `\`, так что для того, чтобы была возможность использовать полученный таким образом путь, нужно, скорее всего, в файл с кодом, который предполагается использовать в качестве движка для создаваемого формата экспорта, включить участок для замены `/` на `\`. Будем иметь это ввиду в дальнейшем. Сопоставляя порядок перечисления параметров в файле lyxrc.defaults, с которыми мы заставляем запускаться (а, быть иожет, и запускиваться)) ) файл puti.bat, сам файл puti.bat с содержимым файла puti.txt, я заключаю, что для создания других форматов экспорта, задуманных мной, нам понадобятся, в принципе, только обозначения двух переменных РАТН в форме, понятной LyX. Это $$i - переменная, которая после подстановки выводит в файл puti.txt имя того файла .tex, который нам нужно получить из редактируемого в настоящий момент файла .lyx, для того, чтобы сразу после этого получения было, на что натравливать тот обрабатывающий файл из арсенала установленной и настроенной программы MiKTeX, который мы и наметили для создаваемого нами формата экспорта - всв в полном соответствии с процессом экспорта в имеющиеся изначально, от авторов программы, форматы. В качестве такого обрабатывающего файла можно использовать созданный мной файл с кодом какого-нибудь расширения. И $$r - немного измененной по своей специфике программы LyX путь до папки с тем файлом .lyx, экспортом которого в наш формат мы в начале этого экспорта получим файл .tex, о котором мы только что говорили. Как видно на приведенном мной фото модифицированного мной меню Экспорт, я на своем компе не ограничился созданием одного нового формата экспорта puti. Остановимся подробнее на этих созданных мной форматах экспорта. Обычно при экспорте в какой-нибудь "родной" формат программы LyX все попутно возникающие при этом файлы помещаются программой LyX в соответствующий временный каталог. Попробуем создать такой формат экспорте, при работе которого эти файлы будут помещаться в одну папку с экспортируемым файлом .lyx. Ну, действия с файлом *lyxrc.defaults* будут по сути такими же, как действия с этим файлом при создании формата экспорта puti. Так же добавляю в соответствующие места этого файла строки

```
\Format pdf7 pdf "pdflatex v papke" F "pdfview" "" "document,vector,menu=export"
```

и

```
\converter pdflatex pdf7 "pdflatex-v-papke.bat $$r $$i" ""
```

, тут все понятно. Настоящее отличие между созданным нами ранее форматом экспорта *puti* и форматом экспорта, создаваемым сейчас, обусловлено отличием между движками (в данном случае между файлами .bat), который мы поставили на тот формат экспорта и который поставим на этот формат. Именно, в качестве движка для этого формата мы будем использовать файл pdflatex-v-papke.bat следующего содержания:

```
cd /d %0\..
chcp 1251
echo LYXCMD:sohranenie:buffer-write> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod)
:vhod
echo %1 > put0.txt
echo cd /d %%0\..>> pereim.bat
echo SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion>> pereim.bat
echo Set infile=put0.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set outFile=put.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set find=/>>pereim.bat
echo Set replace=\>>pereim.bat
echo for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%%%n in ("%%infile%%") do (>> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=%%%%n">> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=!LINE:%%find%%=%%replace%%!">> 
pereim.bat
echo echo.!LINE!^>^>%%outFile%%>> pereim.bat
echo )>> pereim.bat
echo exit>> pereim.bat
start /b pereim.bat
:vhod1
if exist put.txt (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)
:vyhod1
echo chcp 1251 > perehod.bat
echo cd /D^^>>perehod.bat
more < put.txt >> perehod.bat
echo del %~n2.tex>> perehod.bat
echo :vhod2 >> perehod.bat
echo lyx -e latex %~n2.lyx>> perehod.bat
echo if exist %~n2.tex (goto :vyhod2) else (goto 
:vhod2) >> perehod.bat
echo :vyhod2 >> perehod.bat
echo pdflatex %2 >> perehod.bat
echo taskkill /f /im pdflatex.exe >> perehod.bat
echo exit >> perehod.bat
echo :vhod3
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod3)
:vyhod3
start perehod.bat
pdflatex %1 rem без этого невозможен просмотр в создавемом на базе этого файла движке
exit.bat
exit
```

Как работает этот батник? Прежде всего, глядя на то, с какими параметрами я сделал этот батник вызывающимся программой LyX, прописав это в файле lyxrc.defaults, мы видим, что это происходит с параметрами "путь к папке, содержащий экспортируемый файл в специфичной для LyX форме" и "имя экспортируемого файла, но с расширением .tex", причем порядок параметров важен. Итак, этот батник вначале производит переход во временную папку, в которой при экспорте в какой-нибудь "родной формат" образуются сопутствующие файлы. Затем, ввиду возможности наличия в параметрах запуска батника pdflatex-v-papke.bat кириллических букв, мы в окне командной строки, в которой будет выполняться этот батник, меняем кодировку на windows 1251. Потом, пользуясь возможностью прогры LyX быть восприимчивой к командам из командной строки, про которую (возможность) я рассказывал [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066881/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-lyx), мы, ввиду возможности появления изменений в экспортируемом файле, перед главными действиями с этим файлом, вначале сохраняем экспортируемый файл .lyx командой

```
echo LYXCMD:sohranenie:buffer-write> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
```

, чтобы каждый раз не делать это вручную. Команда

```
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod)
```

с используемыми в ней метками *:vyhod3* и *:vhod* стоящими до и после этой команды, сама по себе ничего не создает, а делает вот что. Следующими файлами, появляющимися в соответствующей временной папке в результате работы батника pdflatex-v-papke.bat, являются (в порядке появления) файлы *put0.txt*, *pereim.bat*, *put.txt*, *perehod.bat*, создавать их при каждом предпросмотре, экспорте, во всяком случае, при возможных редактированиях открытого в настоящий момент файла .lyx, не нужно, это нужно только в первый раз. При этом в этот первый раз последним во временном каталоге создастся файл perehod.bat, 3 остальных из этих файлов во временной папке не будут существовать, если в этой папке не будет существовать этого файла. Поэтому-то в условии *if* мы и пишем существование этого файла. Если, когда батник pdflatex-v-papke.bat начинает работать, в соответствующей временной папке этого файла не существует, батник pdflatex-v-papke.bat идет по ветке, создающей в соответствующей временной папке 4 файла - put0.txt, pereim.bat, put.txt, perehod.bat и переходит к последующим своим командам. Если же эти 4 файла во временном каталоге уже существуют, происходит сразу переход к последующим командам, о которых я говорил в предыдущем предложении. Остановимся подробнее на этих четырех файлах. Т. к. первым параметром, с которым програ LyX запускает файл pdflatex-v-papke.bat, является "путь к папке, содержащий экспортируемый файл в специфичной для LyX форме", то в файл *put0.txt* будет выводится этот путь, представленный в этой форме. Однако путь в этой форме непригоден для использования в командной строке (там разделителем, так сказать, различных уровней вложенности папок является знак `/` вместо ожидаемого командной строкой знака `\`). По этой причине следующим этапом работы файла pdflatex-v-papke.bat является создание в том же временном каталоге батника pereim.bat, работа которого заключается в том, чтобы взять содержимое файла put0.txt, заменить в этом содержимом `/` на `\` и записать полученное в файл put1.txt. Следующим действием pdflatex-v-papke.bat является запуск батника pereim.bat. Чтобы при этом не появлялось черное окно выполнения командной строки этого батника, мы к команде, запускающей этот батник, добавим ключ /b. Я сделал (не знаю, почему) файл pereim.bat запускающимся в отдельном окне командной строки. Из-за этого, пока он генерирует файл put1.txt, работа основного файла pdflatex-v-papke.bat переходит на следующие этапы, на которых в соответствующем временном каталоге уже предполагается существование файла put1.txt. По этой причине в работе основного файла pdflatex-v-papke.bat может произойти ошибка. Чтобы этого не произошло, следующим действием после запуска батника *pereim.bat* является зацикливание основного батника таким участком его кода:

```
:vhod1
if exist put.txt (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)
:vyhod1
```

Этим участком кода проверяется наличие файла *put.txt* во временном каталоге, соответствующем экспортируемому файлу. Если этого файла в этой папке нет, батник возвращается к метке `:vhod1` и снова проверяет наличие файла *put.txt* во временном каталоге, соответствующем экспортируемому файлу и так до тех пор, пока этот файл в этой папке не появится. Как только проверка обнаружит этот файл, происходит выход из цикла и выполнение последующих команд батника *pdflatex-v-papke.bat*. А следующими этапами работы этого батника является создание в соответствующем временном каталоге батника *perehod.bat*, ожидание появления этого батника (за это отвечает участок кода

```
:vhod3
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto 
:vhod3)
:vyhod3
```

батника pdflatex-v-papke.bat) и запуск батника *perehod.bat*. Батник *perehod.bat* мы создаем в отдельном файле потому, что он в процессе своей работы должен перейти по пути, содержащемуся в ранее созданном файле *put.txt* и этот путь из этого файла еще нужно извлечь, что и делается командой

```
more < put.txt
```

А вообще, к примеру, содержание файла *perehod.bat* следующее (при экспортируемом файле `C:\DocLyX\newfile2.lyx`):

```
chcp 1251
cd /D^
C:\DocLyX\
del newfile2.tex
:vhod2
lyx -e latex newfile2.lyx
if exist newfile2.tex (goto :vyhod2) else (goto :vhod2)
:vyhod2
pdflatex newfile2.tex
taskkill /f /im pdflatex.exe exit
```

А этот батник что делает? Вначале, ввиду возможности наличия в полном пути к экспортируемому файлу кириллических букв, кодировка командного окна, в котором начинает выполняться батник *perehod.bat*, переключается на windows 1251. Затем выполняются следующие 2 строки, на самом деле являющимися одной командой. Сцепление этих строк в одну команду выполняется знаком `^` в конце первой строки. Смысл этой составной команды в том, что работа батника *perehod.bat* переносится в папку с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx`. Ключ же `/D` добавлен потому, что у меня в программе LyX в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути** в текстовом поле *Временный каталог* выставлено так, что при открытии программы LyX этот Временный каталог создается на диске, отличном от того, в некоторой папке которого обычно запускается командная строка. Далее происходит удаление одноименного с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` файла, но с расширением `.tex`, который, быть может, был получен в одной папке с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` при экспортах экспортируемого файла `.lyx`, произведенных ранее. Далее по идее должен производиться экспорт файла `.lyx`, с которым мы сейчас возимся, в формат `.tex` с последующим зацикливанием батника *pdflatex-v-papke.bat* до появления в соответствующем временном каталоге файла, одноименного с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` файла, но с расширением `.tex`. Однако, при таком порядке команд иногда происходит зацикливание (бесконечное) батника *pdflatex-v-papke.bat*, потому что одноименного с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` файла, но с расширением `.tex` так и не появилось. Поэтому команду экспорта в `.tex` лучше поместить после той метки, к которой батник возвращается в случае отсутствия в папке с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` файла, одноименного с этим файлом .lyx файла, но с расширением `.tex`. Ну, а дальше все просто. Происходит обработка pdflatex'ом файла, одноименного с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` файла, но с расширением `.tex`, потом дается команда уничтожения процессов pdflatex, возможно, оставшихся незакрытыми после этой обработки (такое бывает) и закрытие батника *perehod.bat*. Вернемся к файлу *pdflatex-v-papke.bat*. Этим батником, после запуска батника *perehod.bat*, выполняется команда, смысл которой указан в комментарии к этой команде. А вот далее следует запуск совершенно на первый взгляд не нужного батника *exit.bat* (находящегося в какой-нибудь добавленной в РАТН папке) с еще более странным содержимым

```
date /t
exit
```

А зачем этот батник? Дело в том, что, когда я еще экспериментировал с батником *puti.bat*, я, среди прочих подобных, пробовал не роль движка одного из моих форматов файл *puti1.bat*, так вот, когда я в этом и в других файлах, используемых для подобных целей, не указывал запуска этого батника, у меня, когда я выполнял в LyX экспорт в соответствующий мной созданный формат, упорно вылезала следующая ошибка:

[image]

И я никак не мог понять, как от нее избавиться. Потом, чисто случайно, у меня в батнике *puti1.bat* предпоследней командой оказалась команда запуска какого-то батника. Эта ошибка появляться перестала. Насколько я помню, тот случайный батник своей работой генерировал какие-то файлы. Мне это было не нужно. Тогда я решил попробовать в этот батник поместить какую-нибудь не производящую никакие файлы команду. Попробовал дату. Получилось: ошибка, приведенная на фото, перестала выплывать. Так и оставил. Хотя, хоть убей, не пойму, почему это помогает, а узнать, почему это срабатывает, было бы интересно. Ну, а дальше идет выход из батника *pdflatex-v-papke.bat*. Вот и все. Так, далее. В TeXworks есть следующий инструмент верстки:

[image]

Создадим в LyX формат экспорта, который вначале производит экспорт экспортируемого файла `.lyx` в `.tex`, а затем на полученный файл `.tex` будет натравливаться `xelatex.exe` с опцией `-undump=xelatex`. При этом все файлы, попутно создающиеся при экспорте в этот формат какого-нибудь файла `.lyx`, будут помещаться в одну папку с экспортируемым файлом. Действия, полностью аналогичные описанным выше. Этот формат делаем отображающимся в **Файл>Экспортировать в...** под именем *xelatex v papke*, ставим на этот формат экспорта движок *xelatex-v-papke.bat* следующего содержания:

```
cd /d %0\..
chcp 1251
echo LYXCMD:sohranenie:buffer-write> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod)
:vhod
echo %1 > put0.txt
echo cd /d %%0\..>> pereim.bat
echo SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion>> pereim.bat
echo Set infile=put0.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set outFile=put.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set find=/>>pereim.bat
echo Set replace=\>>pereim.bat
echo for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%%%n in ("%%infile%%") do (>> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=%%%%n">> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=!LINE:%%find%%=%%replace%%!">> pereim.bat
echo echo.!LINE!^>^>%%outFile%%>> pereim.bat
echo )>> pereim.bat
echo exit>> pereim.bat
start /b pereim.bat
:vhod1
if exist put.tex (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)
:vyhod1
echo chcp 1251 > perehod.bat
echo cd /D^^>>perehod.bat
more < put.txt >> perehod.bat
echo del %~n2.tex>> perehod.bat
echo :vhod2 >> perehod.bat
echo lyx -e latex %~n2.lyx>> perehod.bat
echo if exist %~n2.tex (goto :vyhod2) else (goto :vhod2) >> perehod.bat
echo :vyhod2 >> perehod.bat
echo miktex-xetex.exe -undump=xelatex %2 >> 
perehod.bat
echo taskkill /f /im pdflatex.exe >> perehod.bat
echo exit >> perehod.bat
:vhod3
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod3)
:vyhod3
start perehod.bat
pdflatex %1 rem без этого невозможен просмотр в создаваемом на базе этого файла движке
exit.bat
exit
```

Как видно, этот батник имеет точно такую же структуру, что и файл *pdflatex-v-papke.bat*. Отличие только в одной-единственной команде *miktex-xetex.exe -undump=xelatex %2*, которой и производится обработка одноименного с экспортируемым в создаваемый сейчас формат файла `.tex`, который мы уже получили в самом начале этого экспорта. И точно так же в файле *lyxrc.defaults* мы делаем, чтобы батник *xelatex-v-papke.bat* запускался с параметрами $$r $$i, указываемыми в файле *lyxrc.defaults* непременно в этом порядке. Отмечу, что, чтобы этот формат экспорта работал с файлами `.lyx`, в которых есть кириллические буквы, в преамбуле полученного перед этим файле `.tex` должна либо отсутствовать опция *utf8* в *\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}*, либо вообще отсутствовать последняя команда. Последнее (кстати, очень полезная штука: таким образом в недоступной части преамбулы можно удалить inputenc и через **Документ>Настройки>Преамбула LaTeX** написать так, как нужно по этому поводу) достигается установкой в **Документ>Настройки>Язык** в переключателе *Кодировка* значения выпадающего списка *Другая* (название этого списка зависит от используемого файла локализации `.mo`) в *Юникод (XeTeX) (utf8)*. В качестве последнего примера рассмотрим создание формата экспорта, при экспорте в который, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия в экспортируемом файле кода графики Asymptote, выполняется та или иная последовательность команд (pdflatex+asymptote+pdflatex или просто pdflatex). При этом, независимо от того, есть или нет в этом файле код графики Asymptote, все файлы, попутно возникающие при работе ТеХ, будут образовываться не в соответствующем временном каталоге, а в одной с экспортируемым файлом `.lyx` папке. При этом, если в экспортируемом файле `.lyx` все-таки есть код графики Asymptote, в конечном `.pdf` в месторасположениях, соответствующим месторасположениям кодам графики Asymptote, будет находиться уже готовая соответствующая графика. Перед вставкой в файл `.lyx` кода Asymptote в место будущего нахождения этого кода вставляем код TeX
(`Ctrl`+`L`), в этот блок кода вставляем какое-нибудь слово-абракадабру, которое точно ни в каком другом месте этого файла `.lyx` попадаться не будет - условимся использовать для этого какое-нибудь русское слово, записанное (латиницей) для большей сумбурности в обратном порядке. Пусть это слово-абракадабра будет *ovols*. Пишем это слово-абракадабру во вставленный блок кода TeX, далее в этом блоке 
TeX вставляем пустую строку, новую строку и в этой новой строке набираем опять слово ovols. В пустую строку между этими ovols'ами вставляем \begin{asy}, 2 новые строки и во второй новой строке вписываем \end{asy}. При желании последовательность этих всех действий можно автоматизировать с помощью файла `.js` соответствующего содержания. Быть может, потом я об этом напишу подробнее. И, наконец, между этими тегами asy пишем код требуемого рисунка. Выглядеть это, например, может выглядеть так:

[image]

слово-абракадабра нужна потому, что, когда я этот прием не использовал, то при просмотре созданного при экспорте в формат pdflatex файла `.tex` в соответствующем временном каталоге пустые строки, вставляемые до и после окружения *asy*, исчезали, что приводило к появлению конечного `.pdf`, отличающегося от того, которое было задумано. Далее, естественно, не забываем подключить пакет *asymptote* в **Документ>Настройки...>Преамбула LaTeX**. В файле *lyxrc.defaults* указываем движок для этого формата все с теми же параметрами *$$r* *$$i*. Пришла пора привести код для движка этого формата. Это будет, как всегда, файл `.bat`. Назовем его *pdflatex+asymptote+pdflatex-v-lyx.bat*. Как всегда, этот файл должен находиться в папке, добавленной в РАТН. Вот код этого батника:

```
cd /d %0\..
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod6) else (goto :vhod)
:vhod
echo %1 > put0.txt
echo cd /d %%0\..> pereim.bat
echo SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion>> pereim.bat
echo Set infile=put0.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set outFile=put.txt>> pereim.bat
echo Set find=/>>pereim.bat
echo Set replace=\>>pereim.bat
echo for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%%%n in ("%%infile%%") do (>> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=%%%%n">> pereim.bat
echo set "LINE=!LINE:%%find%%=%%replace%%!">> pereim.bat
echo echo.!LINE!^>^>%%outFile%%>> pereim.bat
echo )>> pereim.bat
echo exit>> pereim.bat
start /b pereim.bat
:vhod1
if exist put.txt (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)
:vyhod1
echo echo LYXCMD:sohranenie:buffer-write^> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in >perehod.bat
echo cd /D ^^>>perehod.bat
more < put.txt >> perehod.bat
echo :vhod1>>perehod.bat
echo lyx -e latex %~n2.lyx>> perehod.bat
echo if exist %~n2.tex (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)>>perehod.bat
echo :vyhod1>>perehod.bat
echo echo cd /d %%%%0\..^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo chcp 65001^>^> 
zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo Set infile=%~n2.tex^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo Set outFile=zameneno.tex^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo Set find=ovols^>^>zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo Set replace=^>^>zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo for /F "UseBackQ delims=" %%%%%%%%n in ("%%%%infile%%%%") do (^>^>zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo set "LINE=%%%%%%%%n"^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo set "LINE=!LINE:%%%%find%%%%=%%%%replace%%%%!"^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo 
echo.!LINE!^^^>^^^>%%%%outFile%%%%^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo )^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo echo exit^>^> zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo :vhod2>>perehod.bat
echo if exist zamena.bat (goto :vyhod2) else (goto :vhod2)>>perehod.bat
echo :vyhod2>>perehod.bat
echo start zamena.bat>>perehod.bat
echo :vhod3>>perehod.bat
echo if exist zameneno.tex (goto :vyhod3) else (goto :vhod3)>>perehod.bat
echo :vyhod3>>perehod.bat
echo del %~n2.tex>>perehod.bat
echo rename zameneno.tex %~n2.tex>>perehod.bat
echo del %~n2.aux>>perehod.bat
echo if exist %~n2-*.asy (goto :vhod4) else (goto :vhod5)>>perehod.bat
echo :vhod4>>perehod.bat
echo del %~n2-*.*>>perehod.bat
echo :vhod5>>perehod.bat
echo pdflatex %2 >> perehod.bat
echo for %%%%f in (%~n2-*.asy) do asy %%%%f >> perehod.bat
echo pdflatex %2 >> perehod.bat
echo exit >> perehod.bat
:vhod6
if exist perehod.bat (goto :vyhod6) else (goto :vhod6)
:vyhod6
start perehod.bat
```

В принципе, здесь все то же самое. Только файл zamena.bat нужен для замены ovols ничем, т. е. для удаления этого слова-абракадабры. Как обычно, участки кода вида

```
:vhod «с таким-то номером»
If exist «такой-то файл»...
:vyhod «с таким же таким-то номером»
```

служат для, так сказать, приостановки дальнейших действий соответствующего батника до появления «такого-то файла» в рабочей папке этого батника, хотя на самом деле батник продолжает работу.

Comment: Извините за огромный ответ, просто много сопутствующих деталей.